# Apple .ibooks or ePub file as APP

Tags: ios, ipad, epub, ibooks

I wonder if is it possible to have an home screen "link" to an ibooks file (created with Apple iBooks Author) or if is it possible to "convert" an ibook to a local app..
I don't need to sell or to deliver the ebook via itunes or AppStore.. it's for our corporate internal use.

Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a link to the home screen is possible.

If you stick with iBooks you could set up a separate collection within the iBooks library to separate corporate content from everything else.

Alternatively, you might like to look at reproducing your iBook as a website and use HTML5 local storage so that it is still available for use when the network is not available. You can then create a link to that website on the home screen. There are some limitations on HMTL5 local storage on mobile Safari compared to full blown Safari (support for audio being one currently) but otherwise the migration should be pretty straightforward since your ePub is essentially a zipped up website.